# Result of a $2D$ random walk with position dependent probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, recurrence-relations

I was just wondering about $2D$ random walks when I got the idea of a position dependent $2D$ random walk:

> A man is initially at $(x,y)$ and can move in a line parallel to the  X and Y-axis only. The probability that the man takes a step in the X-direction is $\frac {|x|}{|x|+|y|}$ and the probability that the man takes a step along the Y-direction is $\frac {|y|}{|x|+|y|}$. Given that the man takes a step in the X-direction the probability that he takes a step in $+$ve x-direction is $\frac {|x|}{1+|x|}$ and that he takes a step along the negative X-direction is $\frac 1{1+|x|}$. Given that he takes a step in the y-direction probability that he takes a step along the positive Y-direction is $\frac 1{1+|y|}$ and probability that he takes a step in the negative Y-direction is $\frac {|y|}{1+|y|}$.
>
> Find the probability that his motion along a direction stops after $n$ steps. Also find probability that his motion stops along a direction at some point of time. (Consider that reaching the origin at any point of time will terminate his walk.)

I have no idea about how to do the question, I think some kind of recurrence relation would help but which one?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "find the probability that his motion along a direction stops after n steps"?

Comment: @muaddib, for example, if the man reaches the y-axis, the the x-coordinate is 0, hence the probability of his taking a step in the y-direction is 0 and now he moves only along the x-direction, so his motion has stopped in the y-direction....this is what i mean..

Comment: Did you intentionally make the problem "anti-symmetric," or was that a typo?  I notice that moving positive on the $y$-axis gets less and less likely with bigger $y$, but moving positive on the $x$ axis gets more and more likely with bigger $x$.

Comment: No, it was intentional, I wanted the probability to be a number that is not too small and not too big..

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi: Your question is interesting but also somewhat challenging. A related, simpler question with fixed probabilities is treated by *[David. K. Neal](http://www.e.ijpam.eu/contents/articles/201300602001.pdf)*. You could  think about *moving* your question to *[MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)*, since you already have another question with nearly identical context in MSE. Find *[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5028)* some info about moving a question to MO. I'm keen to get an appropriate solution to your question. Please inform me, if you get one. Regards,

Comment: I think Michael's answer is correct...

Answer (score 4):

Once the x-coordinate reaches 0, it never leaves.  Same for the y-coordinate. Let's compute the probability that we eventually get $x=0$.

Define $t_k$ as the time just after the $k$th horizontal step (define $t_0=0$). Define $X(t_k)$ as the x-coordinate just after the $k$th horizontal step.  Then $\{X(t_0), X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots\}$ is a 1-d Markov random walk with: 
$$ Pr[X(t_{k+1}) = i+1| X(t_k)=i] = \frac{i}{i+1} \: \: \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\} $$
Assume we start at a positive integer $X(t_0)=x_0>0$. For $i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ define: 
$$ p_i = \mbox{Probability we eventually reach 0, given we start at $x$-location $i$} $$
Then $p_0=1$, and we get the recurrence relation: 
$$ p_i = \left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)p_{i+1} + \left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)p_{i-1} \: \: \forall i \in \{1,2, 3, \ldots\} $$
Manipulating this equation gives: 
$$ \frac{p_{i+1}-p_i}{p_i-p_{i-1}} = \frac{1}{i}  $$
Multiplying this equation over $i \in \{1, \ldots, K\}$ gives: 
$$ \frac{1}{K!} = \prod_{i=1}^{K} \frac{p_{i+1}-p_i}{p_i-p_{i-1}} = \frac{p_{K+1}-p_K}{p_1-p_0}$$
Hence, for all $K \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$: 
$$ p_{K+1}-p_K = \frac{(p_1-p_0)}{K!}$$
Clearly the above also holds for $K=0$.  Thus, summing over $K \in \{0, 1, \ldots, M-1\}$ for $M>0$ gives: 
$$  p_M-p_0 = (p_1-p_0)\sum_{K=0}^{M-1}\frac{1}{K!}  $$
Since $p_0=1$ we have for all $M>0$: 
$$ p_M = 1 - (1-p_1)\sum_{K=0}^{M-1} \frac{1}{K!} $$
However, the positive drift of this Markov chain shows that $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} p_M=0$.  Thus: 
$$ 0 = \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} p_M = 1-(1-p_1)e $$
and hence $p_1 = 1-1/e$. Hence, for all $M \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ we get:
$$ \boxed{p_M = 1 - \frac{1}{e}\sum_{K=0}^{M-1}\frac{1}{K!}  } $$

---

As a minor detail, it can be shown that, given $x>0$, we will eventually (with prob 1) take another step along the horizontal direction (regardless of the current $y$ value).  Thus,  $\{X(t_0), X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots \}$ either goes on forever, or stops when we reach 0.  Same for when $y>0$.

The probability of eventually hitting $y=0$, given the initial location of $y$, can be computed similarly.  The event of eventually hitting the $x$-axis is independent of the event of eventually hitting the $y$-axis, so the probability of eventually hitting both is just the product of the two.

The problem defines the vertical motion to have a negative drift (different from the horizontal motion). So, the probability of eventually hitting $y=0$ is equal to 1.

Overall, given initial location $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0 \geq 0$, $y_0\geq 0$, the probability of eventually reaching $(0,0)$ is $p_{x_0}$ (as defined in the boxed equation above), so it does not depend on $y_0$. Of course, if we ever do reach $(0,0)$, the time required to do so depends on $y_0$.

---

Here is a possibly helpful thought experiment:  Imagine simulating the system as follows: Fix $(x_0,y_0)\geq (0,0)$. Generate an infinite sequence $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ as a 1-d Markov random walk with $A_0=x_0$, and with state $0$ absorbing (and with appropriate transition probabilities, i.e., $Pr[A_{k+1}=i+1|A_k=i]=\frac{i}{i+1}$ for $i>0$).  *Independently generate* an infinite sequence $\{B_0, B_1, B_2, \ldots\}$ as a 1-d Markov random walk with $B_0=y_0$ and with state $0$ absorbing (and with $Pr[B_{k+1}=i+1|B_k=i]=\frac{1}{i+1}$ for $i>0$).

Now generate the 2-d $(X(t),Y(t))$ process as follows: 
Define $(X(0),Y(0))=(A_0,B_0)$.  For all slots $t \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ do: If $(X(t),Y(t))=(0,0)$, choose $(X(t+1),Y(t+1))=(0,0)$.  Else, independently flip a biased coin with $Pr[HEADS] = \frac{X(t)}{X(t)+Y(t)}$. If HEADS, define $Y(t+1)=Y(t)$ and define $X(t+1)$ as the next unused $A_k$ value.  If TAILS, define $X(t+1)=X(t)$ and define $Y(t+1)$ as the next unused $B_k$ value.

The sequence $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ in the above thought experiment is exactly what I have been calling the “embedded sequence” $\{X(t_0), X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots\}$.  An example  $\{(X(t),Y(t))\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ trajectory is: $$ \{(\boxed{A_0},B_0), (A_0, B_1), (A_0,B_2), (\boxed{A_1}, B_2), (\boxed{A_2},B_2), (A_2, B_3), (A_2, B_4), (\boxed{A_3}, B_4), (A_3, B_5),  \ldots\} $$ where I have boxed the embedded sequence $\{X(t_k)\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$.

The $\{A_k\}$ and $\{B_k\}$ sequences are independent of each other (by their construction).  Also:

i) $X(t)$ eventually hits 0 if and only if $\{A_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ eventually hits zero.

ii) $Y(t)$ eventually hits 0 if and only if $\{B_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ eventually hits zero.

Comment: I have a doubt in your solution, you have said that the event of the person reaching $x=0$ is independent of the vertical motion, but I believe that contrary to that, the probability that the man takes a step in the y- direction as you move towards $x=0$..and also how did you arrive to the recurrence relation that $p_i = \left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)p_{i+1} + \left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)p_{i-1} \: \: \forall i \in \{1,2, 3, \ldots\}$?

Comment: Let $A$ be the event of eventually hitting $x=0$. Restricting attention only to times when $x$ moves, we get $p_i=Pr[A|x=i]=Pr[A|x=i, \mbox{first jump right}]\frac{i}{i+1} + Pr[A|x=i, \mbox{first jump left}]\frac{1}{i+1}$, which is $p_{i+1}\frac{i}{i+1} + p_{i-1}\frac{1}{i+1}$.

Comment: Note that $Pr[X(t_{k+1})=i+1|X(t_k)=i, Y(t_k)=y_k] = \frac{i}{i+1}$.  There is no dependence on $y_k$ whatsoever (regardless of whether $y_k=0$ or $y_k>0$). So the $y$ location never affects the embedded chain $\{X(t_0), X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots\}$.

Comment: @Michael [I deleted my last comment which has become obsolete since your last edit]. You claim that "The event of eventually hitting the $x$-axis is independent of the event of eventually hitting the $y$-axis". Could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy , I added a new section to my answer above (a simulation thought experiment) to address your question about independence between the up/down and left/right motion.